# Alternative word for jealous (without the negative connotations)

Tags: synonyms, connotation, nonsubjective

I was wondering whether there is a word similar to jealousy but without the negative connotations? For example, if I really admired someone for their memory and wished mine could be as good - however, I didn't feel begrudging of their good memory, or wished I could have good memory and they didn't. 
Basically, a word meaning I'm happy for someone for their good fortune, but wished I also had it.

Thank you :)

Comment: It still seems none of the words put forth in answers here fully describe that feeling, at least in my opinion. I wonder if there is a German word with that exact quality? I believe that language is known for words that represent precise feelings. eg: schadenfreude.

Comment: This is surely a form of ambivalence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Envious is a term which fits your description.

Comment: Or, better yet, desirous, which has no negative connotation whatsoever.

Comment: @Elise But you are *desirous* of Joe's memory, not of Joe -- that would imply something quite different!

Comment: At the risk of going down a grammar-cliche rabbit-hole, jealous and envious do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @DJClayworth: can you add an answer or else comment explaining why?

Comment: In their original meanings, jealous and envious were not synonyms. 'Jealous' was used for being protective of what was yours, and 'envious' was used for desiring what someone else has. A 'jealous' husband was not one who wanted another's wife, but one who wanted to guard his wife from the attentions of others. Usage has since blurred the two meanings.

Answer (score 2):

I found 2 answers that worked for me.

"Aspire", as in "I aspire to have what you have".

Or "benign envy". They did a whole research paper on it! http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/not-jealous-others-success-13972.html

Answer (score 1):

**Wish** may be the word you want.

> I wish I had memories as nice as yours.

Comment: Seems a reasonable offering to me

Answer (score 0):

I think **intrigued** might be a better fit.

> a mysterious or fascinating quality.

Answer (score 0):

Compersion! Finding pleasure in the pleasure of someone you love.

Comment: Hello, Alyssa. If this is a 'word' you've just invented, a DIY portmanteau, please be aware that ELU looks at standard usages. Also, good answers are expected to be accompanied by linked and attributed supporting references.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It appears to be what you said, a word recently invented, but not necessarily by this particular answerer. https://www.google.com/search?q=Compersion

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for a positive meaning to jealous. I think the best that I came up with was “desirous” You can desire something someone else has but at the same time want them to continue with that desirous attribute. Also the idea of being protective of something that is good as for them and for you if you could acquire it. So instead of saying “I am jealous for what you have,” you can say “I am desirous also for what you have.“